# Message not being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

Okay, I know I'm an amateur and I have asked a ton of questions recently. I've fixed it so I cannot input a duplicate record to my sql server database. Here is the code for that:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

 SqlConnection User = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CONNECTION STRING BLAH BLAH");
 {
    User.Open();
     string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdatabase where Username = @username";
     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, User);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", InputUsername.Text);
     int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
     User.Close();
     if (temp == 1)
     {
     Response.Write("Username is already in use");
     }
     if (temp == 0)
     {

     SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into userdatabase(ID,Username, Email, Password, Fname, LName, Addl1, AddL2,
City, County, Postcode, Country, Company)Values(@ID, @Username,
@Email, @Password, @FName, @LName, @AddL1, @AddL2, @City, @County,
@Postcode, @Country, @Company )", User);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newGUID.ToString());
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", InputUsername.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", InputEmail.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", InputPassword.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", InputFname.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", InputSname.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddL1", InputAddress1.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddL2", InputAddress2.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", InputCity.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", InputState.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", InputPostcode.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", InputCountry.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company",InputCompany.Text);


     User.Open();
     xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
     User.Close();
     }
     if (IsPostBack)
     {
     InputUsername.Text = "";
     InputPassword.Text = "";
     InputEmail.Text = "";
     VerifyPassword.Text = "";
     InputFname.Text = "";
     InputSname.Text = "";
     InputAddress1.Text = "";
     InputAddress2.Text = "";
     InputCity.Text = "";
     InputState.Text = "";
     InputPostcode.Text = "";
     InputCompany.Text = "";

     Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

     }

 }


}

protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

} }
```

However, as you can see I've set it to write "username is already in use". But it doesn't display it and it doesn't input data onto the table. It also redirects it to the login.aspx page. Any help with stopping the page from redirecting to a new page and with the message displaying?

**Edit**

someone mentioned about a try/ catch method for this to work, would anyone be able to explain to me how this works, i've looked on YouTube but i haven't found anything that would be able to help with this

Comment: you can use try,catch and finally blocks,so that you can catch the exception and display the error message?

Comment: `Password` is keyword enclose it in square brackets. `[Password]`

Comment: On a slightly different note, I would advise that you move all of your function code from your `button1_Click` event into a separate method, and then call it, as this is better practice and also removes responsibility from your `UI`.  Ideally the code doing all the work would be in a separate class, but that is something for another day.